# select range of element from array json

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-json

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.rows[*]') AS name from my_table ;
```

the data col is json col and contain rows as an array element need to select a range of element from row [like a pagination ]

try to make pagination from DB direct to select for example 1st page with size 25 then 2nd page but start from the last of 1st one and son.

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"rows":[{"name":"name_1"},{"name":"name_2"},{"name":"name_3"},{"name":"name_4"}]} |

Comment: provide sample data according to [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), #5 and #3.

Comment: check, i provide a sample data

Comment: If you stuck that much data into a JSON column, that pagination would be required to display it ... then I'd say that is a rather _bad_ data model to begin with.

Comment: You could access the individual items you need by providing multiple path arguments - `JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.rows[0]', '$.rows[1]', '$.rows[2]')` for your first three items, then `JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.rows[3]', '$.rows[4]', '$.rows[5]')` for the next three, etc. And for more than three items per page, you'd need to add more path selectors then. Not sure if there is a more direct way.

Comment: *i provide a sample data*, but not in useful form. And where is desired output?

Comment: If you have a single large JSON field that contains dozens of rows for pagination, I would say that's an ineffective way of storing data. I would store it differently. Assuming you want to keep it this way, considering that mySQL will have to read the whole field to extract JSON properties each time, it should be quicker to get the whole value once, decode the JSON client-side and paginate from it..

Comment: The JSON datatype always looks convenient at first, but in practice it makes things harder. JSON doesn't fit well with the relational model of SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution:

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT('rows', JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('name', t.name))) AS data
FROM (
  SELECT j.name
  FROM my_table
  CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(my_table.data, '$.rows[*]' COLUMNS (
      ord FOR ORDINALITY,
      name VARCHAR(20) PATH '$.name'
    )
  ) AS j
  WHERE j.ord BETWEEN 1 and 25
) AS t;
```

Use different numbers for the `BETWEEN` arguments to get other "pages" of your array.

If this seems too complex, then you should be storing data in normal rows and columns instead of JSON.